# Get current step running for the Powershell script running on remote machine

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting, powershell-ise

Lets say Server1.ps1  is running on a remote machine which has around 10 steps which get executed sequentially.

I want to monitor the Server1.ps1 script execution from a remote machine through a powershell script.

Not sure if this is a valid/good approach?

Also it would be great if someone can suggest if there is a better way to get the current step running of the script on a remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add a `Write-Event` at each step, writing an event to the Application Event Log, or a custom log when each step starts.  Then you can monitor it remotely using any of the event reader tools or cmdlets.